# C++ Single Producer Multiple Consumer Program Crashes Sporadically

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition, producer-consumer

In the code below, I am creating a `producer thread` and `n` `consumer threads` that read from each of its dedicated `queue` and prints to the `stdout`. From time to time this code crashes at the statement `consumerQueues[id]->empty()`. Going through the debugger I see that `consumerQueues[id]` is `0x0` when it crashes. Now in the `init()` function, I create the `ith` consumer `queue` before the `ith` worker `thread` gets created. I am not sure why `consumerQueues[id]` will remain `0x0`. Please help me figure what is going on.

```
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class Test
{
private:
    void producer()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            std::string s = "abc";
            for(const auto& q : consumerQueues)
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                q->push(s);
                condition_variable.notify_all();
            }
        }
    }

    void consumer(int id)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            std::string job;
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                while(consumerQueues[id]->empty())
                {
                    condition_variable.wait(lock);
                }
                job = consumerQueues[id]->front();
                consumerQueues[id]->pop();
            }
            std::cout << "ID "<< id << " job " << job << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable condition_variable;
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::queue<std::string>>> consumerQueues;
    std::thread producerThread;

public:

    Test(const unsigned n_threads):
    workers(std::vector<std::thread>(n_threads))
    {}

    Test(const Test &) = delete;
    Test(Test &&) = delete;

    Test & operator=(const Test &) = delete;
    Test & operator=(Test &&) = delete;

    void init()
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i)
        {
            consumerQueues.push_back(std::make_shared<std::queue<std::string>>());
            workers[i] = std::thread(&Test::consumer, this, i);
        }
       producerThread  = std::thread(&Test::producer, this);
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        producerThread.join();
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(workers[i].joinable())
            {
                workers[i].join();
            }
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    Test t(1000);
    t.init();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: q is a const shared_ptr& to a queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your init function is modifying the std::vector with no mutex. This modifies the vector at the same time the threads are starting one by one.

To make this work, your init function needs to be something like this:

```
 void init() {
     for (unsigned i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            consumerQueues.push_back(std::make_shared<std::queue<std::string>>());
            workers[i] = std::thread(&Test::consumer, this, i);
     }
     producerThread  = std::thread(&Test::producer, this);
 }
```

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

> **Data races**
>
> The container is modified. If a reallocation happens, all contained
>   elements are modified. Otherwise, no existing element is accessed, and
>   concurrently accessing or modifying them is safe.

A reallocation happens pretty often when it starts at 0 elements and goes to 1000. so you can also reserve the size of the vector to make sure a reallocation is not happening:

```
 void init() {
     consumerQueues.reserve(workers.size());
     for (unsigned i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i) {
            consumerQueues.push_back(std::make_shared<std::queue<std::string>>());
            workers[i] = std::thread(&Test::consumer, this, i);
     }
     producerThread  = std::thread(&Test::producer, this);
 }
```

Comment: As you note - std::queue is not inherently thread safe. Any operation that mutates it in a multithreaded system must lock it/mutex or otherwise synchronise access first.

Comment: But the threads only access the part of the std::vector that was already created.

Comment: *But the threads only access the part of the `std::vector` that was already created* -- but that part will be re-allocated with further `push_back()` operations. You may avoid that by `reserve()`ing sufficient elements prior to the loop in `init()`.

Comment: If a reallocation happens, all elements are modified, So you need to reserve() the size of the vector before then.